# detect when user refresh a page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension that show a popup on certain domains . 
the popup should be displayed each time the user visit the webpage or refresh the current page with one of the targeted domains . 
so first I've putted a listener when the current tab is updated :

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(onTabUpdate);
});
```

the `onTabUpdate` function get executed every time a page is loaded ( I've deleted some unnecessary code like domains test ) :

```
function onTabUpdate(tabId, info, tab) {
//if page is refreshed
if (info.url === undefined) {
    if (info.status == 'loading') {
        console.log('Refresh happened for tab: ' + tabId)
        tabsLoaded = {};
        loadPopup(tabId);
    }
}
//if page is first time loaded 
if (tab.status !== 'complete') {
    return;
} else {
    console.log("page loaded ");
    loadPopup(tabId);

}}
```

the code runs very well and detect when the page is loaded or refreshed , the problem is that when I show the popup and the user close it , the refresh event is triggered and the popup shows again . I think because chrome redraw the DOM and refresh the page . 
So I'm looking way to detect when the **user him self** refresh the page not when chrome does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a hack to do it . I dont think there is a way to do it via chrome native API .
inject a content script into every tab that detect when ever the user refresh the page and send a message :

```
if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage("your_extension_id", "pageRefreshed");
}
```

then a setup a listener in the background script, to catch this message :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (e, sender) {
        if (e == "pageRefreshed") {
            var hostName = extractHostname(sender.tab.url);
            if (partnersList.some(function (el) {
                    return hostName.indexOf(el) !== -1;
                })) {
                loadPopup(sender.tab.id);
            }
        }
    });
```

and voila! problem solved :)